# Conditions on distributions to obey a certain inequality

Tags: probability-distributions

Given a random variable X with (continuous, differentiable) CDF $F(x), x\geq 0$, I want to find conditions under which it satisfies ($\forall a,x\geq 0$):
$$\frac{F(a+x)-F(a)}{x.f(a+x)}\leq\frac{1-F(a)}{1-F(a+x)}$$
The inequality holds for $X\sim Uniform[a,b]$, or $X\sim Exponential(\lambda)$ (easy to check by substituting). In simulations, it seems to hold for any $X\sim Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$, and also the Cauchy distribution.

Some geometrical intuition: if I consider 2 points $a$ and $a+x$ on a CDF $F(x)$, then the LHS is the ratio of how far the function F drops going backward from $a+x$ to $a$, while the denominator is the corresponding drop in the tangent to $F$ at $a+x$. The RHS is the ratio of how far the function $F$ is from $1$ at $a$ vs. $a+x$; note that its always $\geq 1$ as F is always non-decreasing. Now if $F$ is convex at $a+x$, then the inequality is clearly true (the LHS is $<1$ as the tangent drops by more than $F$). This also shows why it works for any uniform distribution.

Essentially I want to know if there is some more well-known condition on distributions that implies this (or if it's always true...).

Comment: So it turns out that a sufficient condition is for $F$ to have a monotone hazard-rate, i.e., $h(t) = f(t)/(1-F(t))$ is non-decreasing.

Comment: For reference, a short proof sketch: MHR means that $h(t) = f(t)/(1-F(t))$ is non-decreasing. Also, from definition, we have $F(x) = 1-\exp\left(-\int_0^xh(t)dt\right)$, and $f(x) = h(x)(1-F(x))$. Substitute in the above expression -- eventually it simplifies to being requiring that $1-xh(a+x)-\exp\left(-\int_{a}^{a+x}h(t)dt\right)<0$. Now using the fact that $h(x)$ is non-decreasing, and $1-x<e^{-x}$, we get the result.
Anyone has a more general condition?